# Excel Nested IF Statement Trouble

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested-if

=IF(J4 >= 20, A, IF(J4 < 20 AND J4 > 13, B, IF(J4 < 14 AND J4 > 8, C, IF(J4 < 8, D,0))))

The numeric values = points
The values A - D is a scoring systems that rates a person based upon their points and gives them a value from A-D.

I've been stuck on this formula for a long time and have no idea what I'm doing wrong, all help would be appretiated!

Comment: You need quotation marks for strings.

Comment: After checking that J4 >= 20, you don't need to check again that J4<20 because you are already in the else branch

Comment: Previously I had the letters referenced in cells on the table, but I put them as strings when asking the question to help anyone reading the post understand.

Comment: I don't think that there is an AND operator, only an AND function, e.g. AND( condition1, condition2 )

Comment: Oh, how should I rewrite the statement?

Comment: Please, next time post code that we can test with copy-paste

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to update your statement as follows.

```
=IF(J4<8,"D",IF(J4<14,"C",IF(J4<20,"B","A")))
```

You can see that it's important in this case to move in one direction, either **low to high**, or **high to low**. This allows us to return a result whenever a test returns TRUE, because we know that the previous tests have returned FALSE.

Comment: Thank you everyone!

Comment: @JoshuaBrown the best way to thank is to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`=IF(J4 >= 20, "A", IF(J4 > 13, "B", IF(J4 > 8, "C", "D")))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formula:

```
=IF(20<=J4,"A",IF(13<=J4,"B",IF(8<=J4,"C",IF(J4<8,"D",0))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax you're using for the AND function is wrong. You need to nest all the parameters you want to use within the AND function. like this:

```
=IF(AND(J4<20,J4>8),"true","false")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another apporach assuming that the possible inputs in J4 are integers below 1000:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX({"A";"B";"C";"D"},MATCH(J4,{1000;19;12;7},-1)),0)
```

I think this one is easier to read and to maintain.